# How to clear Eclipse Neon cache memory during a running pydev code?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, caching, pydev, eclipse-neon

I am coding in Python 2.7 using PyDev on Eclipse Neon IDE on Windows 10. My code is big and has lots of variables. It's a robotics simulation built from scratch so it does lots of computation. I am not proud of the code. But I can't go back and change the whole code to its ideal form.

It runs perfectly when I run it for one case. But, I have to run it multiple times to get a set of data. So I have put it in loop. This is a problem according to my observation.

The execution used to freeze at a random point after at least around a 100 iterations of the loop. I checked online for solutions and taking one suggestion increased the memory available for Eclipse and the performance increased. Now it freezes at around 200+ iterations.

I believe it is easier if I release certain memory at the start of each iteration. I may be absolutely wrong.

I wanted to know if there is a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Please share the relevant code with us.  Please take the 2-minute site [tour]  when you have the opportunity.

Comment: It is very big and I don't think it will make sense even if I posted it here.

Comment: I understand.  It is very important to try to refine what you have to a [mcve], so that someone will try to help.  Otherwise, I'm afraid your question will just hang out there.

Comment: It's strange that you said you raised the memory in Eclipse and it ran more... what if you run it from the command line? Do you have too much output? (you can try redirecting that to a file if that's the case)

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks to all. I was able to find the reason why the program kept hanging. There was a bug in the program. Thanks.